# How to change the background for the newtab in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, background, tabs

I used to work in DarkMode, and I have a darkmode chrome extension to invert all pages' background color into dark.

However, whenever I open a new tab in Chrome, there is always a 10ms moment that the page is white, it creates a flash that hurts my eyes.

It is possible to config the default background color for new tab in Chrome? I'd like to set it into black (#000000)

Answer (score 0):

The only success I have had with changing the default background in Chrome is through extensions.

I would try a different dark mode or [use a theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/morpheon-dark/mafbdhjdkjnoafhfelkjpchpaepjknad).

I use a theme and I only get the theme background, never see a white background.